# ESP8266 client connection to MongoDB

Tags: json, mongodb, curl, arduino, esp8266

I'm trying to post a new record to my MongoDB (actual CouchDB), but it seems that I'm having problems with the format of my request.

I'm using the following code:
(not showing debug and validations)

```
WiFiClient client;
client.connect("172.16.1.4", 5984)

String connStr = "POST /iot/ HTTP/1.1\r\n"
            "Host: user:password@172.16.1.4:5984/ \r\n"
            "Content-Type: application/json\r\n"
            "\r\n"
            "'{\"a\":1}'\r\n\r\n";

client.print(connStr);
```

I get this response back:

> HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request 
>   Server: CouchDB/1.6.1 (Erlang OTP/18) 
>   Date: Sat, 07 Oct 2017 11:57:50 GMT
>  
>   Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
>   Content-Length: 48 Cache-Control: must-revalidate
>
> {"error":"bad_request","reason":"invalid_json"}
>
> HTTP/1.1 400 Bad
>   Request Server: MochiWeb/1.0 (Any of you quaids got a smint?) 
>   Date: Sat, 07 Oct 2017 11:57:50 GMT 
>   Content-Length: 0

I have tried with differet json/data...

Using Linux - I have no problems:

> curl -X POST user:password@172.16.1.4:5984/iot/ -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"a":3}'

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be with the single quotes(') before { and at the end of }

instead of

```
 "'{\"a\":1}'\r\n\r\n"
```

it should be

```
 "{\"a\":1}\r\n\r\n"
```

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't make any difference... :-/

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the line:

```
"Content-Length: " + String(json.length()) + "\r\n"
```

in the header.